# React Redux, store dispatch not triggering update of component

Tags: reactjs, typescript, redux

I implemented React Redux but smthn is wrong, but i don't understand what exactly. Any ideas what is wrong? I'm changing the state, but the value is still the same. I tried useStore() but it takes 0 params. Where i am wrong? If method store.getState() returns not a reference how can i get the state.

**Page**

```
GameStore.subscribe(() => GameStore.getState().number);

let state = GameStore.getState();
GameStore.subscribe(() => state = GameStore.getState());
const MainPage = (props: any) => {

  return (
    <>
        <Card style={{ margin: 15 }} elevation={1}>
          <CardHeader title="Controls"></CardHeader>
          <CardContent>
            {state.number}
          </CardContent>
          <CardActions>
            <Button variant="contained" color="primary"
                    onClick={() => GameStore.dispatch({type: "DECREMENT_NUMBER", payload: 1})}>
              -
            </Button>
            <Button variant="contained" color="primary"
                    onClick={() => GameStore.dispatch({type: "INCREMENT_NUMBER", payload: 1})}>
              +
            </Button>
          </CardActions>
        </Card>
    </>
  );
};

export default MainPage;
```

**Store**

```
import { createStore, Reducer, PreloadedState } from 'redux';

interface IGameState {
  number: number;
}

interface IActionIncrement {
  type: "INCREMENT_NUMBER";
  payload: number;
}

interface IActionDecrement {
  type: "DECREMENT_NUMBER";
  payload: number;
}

type GameAction = IActionIncrement | IActionDecrement;

const gameInitialState: PreloadedState<IGameState> = { number: 0 };

const gameReducer: Reducer<IGameState, GameAction> = (state: IGameState | undefined, action: GameAction): IGameState => {
  if (!state) {
    return gameInitialState;
  }

  switch (action.type) {
    case "INCREMENT_NUMBER":
      return { ...state, number: state.number + action.payload }
    case "DECREMENT_NUMBER":
      return { ...state, number: state.number - action.payload }
    default:
      return state
  }
}

export const GameStore = createStore(gameReducer, gameInitialState);
```

**App**

```
const App = () => {
  return (
    <>
      <Provider store={GameStore}>
        <HeaderCmp/>
        <MainPage/>
        {/*<FirstVarCmp/>*/}
      </Provider>
    </>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
const state: IGameState = useSelector((state: IGameState) => state);
```

Comment: Could you explain where in the large code sample this code should be added/replaced and what it does? Why does it solve the problem?

Answer (score 0):

React has no way of knowing the external variable `state` has changed and thus does not rerender.

You have to "connect" your component to the store, see [this doc](https://react-redux.js.org/api/connect).